# Page not found 404 using spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Im trying to show the .jsp page, i have set the Controller class and the web.xml and servlet.xml. When i run it shows "404 page not found". Can you help me find mistake, step by step. 
Im using intellij idea 2019, tomcat 9

[image]

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showHome(){
        return "nesto";
    }
}
```

This is web.xml and servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

        <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

        <!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

        <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.springdemo" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
```

to

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
```

> You missed **id="viewResolver"**

Comment: can you share your git repo? I am unable to find the bug in your code, I can find it,if I run your code

Answer (score 0):

adding this property to your "InternalResourceViewResolver" bean might help you

```
<property name="order" value="1"/>
```